# Linked Server in SSMS 2014 - Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - The pipe has been ended

Tags: mongodb, ssms, odbc

I'm trying to connect to Mongo database from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio through Linked Servers using Mongo ODBC Driver. Right now I'm testing [Easysoft ODBC Driver](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-mongodb-driver/index.html).

I can connect to the database and can perform some queries. But if I try to execute query which will return a lot of data I receive this error:

```
Msg 109, Level 20, State 0, Line 2
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server.      
(provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - The pipe has been ended.)
```

I receive this error exactly after 31 seconds.  I will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a mongodb developer, but I am not surprised that you had hit the 30 second problem.

See [Do you want a timeout?](https://blog.mongolab.com/2013/10/do-you-want-a-timeout) (mLab Blog) for hints.

> The default driver connection timeout value ranges anywhere from 1 second (e.g. the Node.JS driver in some cases) to 30 seconds (e.g  the Ruby driver), so you really need to think about what the optimal setting is for your use case.

The socket timeout ideally needs to be set to 0 which means 'forever'.

> **Disclaimer**
>   The original answer was posted as a comment by [@RLF](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/26626/rlf)